# Updating objects and their relations using ORMLite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have just started reading about ORMLite since I am interested in using it in an Android application.

I would like to have a feeling of how object relations are/should be persisted with this framework.

For example, if I have these classes:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "bill_items")
class BillItem{...}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "bills")
class Bill {
  @DatabaseField String x;

  List<BillItem> billItems = new ArrayList<BillItem>;

  public void setItems(List<BillItem> billItems) {
    this.billItems = billItems;
  }
}
```

As far as I understand the recommended way to update a `Bill` object would be with something similar to:

```
Dao<Bill, String> billDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Bill.class);
Bill bill = billDao.queryForId(...);

List<BillItem> billItems = ...; //some new list of items
bill.setX("some new value for X");
bill.setItems(billItems);

//saving explicitly the billItems before saving the bill. Is this correct ?
Dao<BillItem, String> billItemDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, BillItem.class);
for(BillItem billItem : billItems)
  billItemDao.update(billItem);

billDao.update(bill);
```

Is this the recommended way to update an object which relations have changed ? (specifically relations with a set of persistent objects, as in the code above).
Somehow I had the impression that it should be a better way to do this.

Also, if I want to use this framework, am I suppose to put in my model classes both domain attributes and persistency related attributes (e.g., foreign and primary keys ?). Wondering if there is a way to avoid this mixing of concerns.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is basically correct although there are some things you can do to improve it.

1. You should use the `@ForeignCollectionField` annotation to mark the `billItems` field.  This will load the collection when you query for a `Bill`.  See the docs on [foreign collections](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection).

   ```
   @ForeignCollectionField
   ForeignCollection<BillItem> billItems;
   ```
2. Instead of doing the updates by hand each time, you can create your own Dao class for `Bill` that overrides the update `update()` method and updates the inner objects on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gray. So the difference would be that the update method of the Dao class for Bill would invoke the Dao class for BillItem in order to iterate among all the billItems and update each of them. So currently there is not a way to automatize this?. Doing it manually does not seem to be fun. Also it seems that I would have to manually check if previous billItems are not anymore in the new billItems list and if that is the case, manually delete them from the database. It is a pity if all this cannot be automatized :(

Comment: @Sergio If you are using a `ForeignCollection` then if you call `billItems.remove(bill)` it will be removed from the collection _and_ the database via the DAO.  You can also call `billItems.update(bill)` to update it when you change it.

Comment: @Sergio The problem is that it is now a collection of proxy objects.  ORMLite has no idea when you've changed an entry in the `billItems` collection unless you tell it that you did.